# Parsing an algebraic expression to find variables

Tags: java, parsing, tree, expression

I am designing an expression parser and I am having trouble figuring out how exactly to parse variables.

It should be able to read expressions such as

(x + 2) * (x +3)

2* x ^ 2

x ^ y

I have already written something that converts these expressions into a tree structure, but I am not exactly sure how to recognize variables

One way I have thought of solving it is by searching through the tree, finding a character, and build a variable object. 
To check for exponents, I'd go to the variable's parent node and check if it is a ^ 
and for the coefficient I would check that node's parent for a *

Is there a more efficient way than this? I am not exactly sure how I would do expressions like

x ^ (2y + 1)

Here is an implementation I wrote that checks if the right node is a variable and sets it's coefficients and exponents.

```
        if(n.hasRight())
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(n.getRight().toString().charAt(0)))
        {

            Token o = TokenMap.getMap().get(n.toString());
            if(o instanceof Exponent)
            {
                expon = Double.parseDouble(n.getLeft().toString());

                Node par = n.getParent();
                Token t = TokenMap.getTok(par.toString());
                if(t instanceof Multiply)
                {
                       Token tl = TokenMap.getTok(par.getLeft().toString());
                       if(tl instanceof Exponent)
                       {
                            coeff = Double.parseDouble(par.getRight().toString());           
                       }
                        else
                       {
                           coeff = Double.parseDouble(par.getLeft().toString());
                       }

                }
            }
            Variable v = new Variable(n.getRight().toString().charAt(0),expon,coeff);
        } parseVar(new ExpressionTree(n.getRight()));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a decent attempt.  Is it working for you?

Comment: Not really, only if the variable is alone like "x". "x^2" does not work. I was wondering if there was a better way to do what I want, this way seems too cluttered to me